# Linux virtual framebuffer

Tags: linux, framebuffer, xorg

I am looking to create a virtual screen in Linux that could be accessed by reasonably standard applications and then the output would not be displayed directly anywhere but sent over network using custom protocol for displaying using proprietary device. Most preferable way would be having it in userspace.

What came to my mind is xf86-video-dummy, but I cannot find any information how to get the screen contents for processing in my application. Note that I am not just trying to make a screenshot once in a while, but I need more like mmap of the framebuffer to be able to get 25-30 frames a second. Any ideas if this is possible with xf86-video-dummy or any other mechanism?

Comment: So just use `tigervnc` and similar?

Comment: I do not intend to use VNC protocol - I am more looking into simplest mechanism that could be used to achieve something similar to VNC. Analyzing code of VNC like solution could be a good starting point though.

Comment: `Xvfb :1 -shmem`

Comment: You can get the contents of the (whole or parts of the) screen with `XGetImage()` on the root window, and you can monitor changes to it with the "Damage" extension, and only transfer the changed areas.

Comment: @jamieguinan, this looks almost like an answer to me. However, browsing through the web I had an impression that Xvfb has been deprecated in favour of xf86-video-dummy, isn't it the case?

Comment: Maybe its deprecated, but Xvfb is Ubuntu 18 LTS, so you can rely on it being there for at least a few years. The `shmem` options dumps shmem id to stdout, then you can use `shmat(2) ` from your capture/transfer program.